# not able to submit form in php

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to create a php page which gets data from mysql. I am getting a list of objects from database and displaying each object in a different form to edit the value and then save the edited value only.
But i am not able to submit the form. and not able to call the json part and jaascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Expert Edit</title>


<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $("myforms").submit(function(){

    alert("before submit");  

    var data = {
      "tag": "editadsdata",
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "http://localhost/expert.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {

        alert("Form submitted successfully.");
      }
    });



            return false;
  });


</script>


</head>
<body>

<?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","expert");


        $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from ads");
   $tmpCount = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<form action=\"\" class=\"myforms\" method=\"post\" accept-charset=\"utf-8\">";
  echo "<h2>New Entry ! $tmpcount</h2>";
  echo "URL : ";
  echo '<td><a href="' . $row['url'] . '">[Link]</a></td>';
  echo "<input hidden=\"true\" name=\"url\"".$row['url']."\">";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "IMAGE : ";
  echo "<img src=\"".$row['imagepath']."\" />";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "CATEGORY : ";
  echo "<input type=\"text\" name = \"category\" value=\"".$row['category']."\">";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "SUB-CATEGORY : ";
  echo "<input type=\"text\" name = \"subcategory\" value=\"".$row['subcategory']."\">";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "DESCRIPTION : ";
  echo "<input type=\"text\" name = \"description\" value=\"".$row['description']."\">";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "PRICE RANGE : ";
  echo $row['pricerange'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo "TAG : ";
  echo "<input type=\"text\" name = \"tags\" value=\"".$row['tag']."\">";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "UPLOADED BY : ";
  echo $row['uploadedby'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"submit\" />";  
  echo "</form>";
  $tmpcount++;
 }

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>



  </body></html>
```

check this out. This is working but this is in html. I want it it php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;            charset=UTF-8">
  <title>demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript'    src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-   light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.myForms').submit(function () {
alert($(this).attr("id"));
return true;
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
 <form action="http://www.google.com" method="get"    class="myForms" id="1stform">
    <input type="text" value="1st Form" name="q1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit ALL" />
</form>
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="get"     class="myForms" id="2ndform">
 <input type="text" value="2nd Form" name="q2" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit ALL" />
</form>
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="get"  class="myForms" id="3rdform">
<input type="text" value="3rd Form" name="q3" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit ALL" />
</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to submit"?

Comment: As the answer below says, you're not calling an id or a class in your jQuery selector.

Answer (score 8):

Because you use:  `$("myforms")`. No element like this. If myforms is the id of your form then use:

```
$('#myforms')
```

if this is the class of it then

```
$('.myforms')
```

Also you have some error in ajax:

```
var data = {
  "tag": "editadsdata",
};
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
```

Because you defined the data is json, and you overwrite the data with a string, it will fail.

Comment: I am using a class of form and it is valid to use that. But the problem is i need to call the submit function. You can add an action for class and it works

Comment: You have only $("myforms"). That won't work.

Comment: i tried using the same code in normal html with 3,4 forms with the data and tried to submit the same with the myforms submit function, and it is working. But the problem comes when i use php

Comment: Yes, because the form just submitted, but it never will enter the `submit` jQuery function.

Comment: @lolka_bolka i have edited the code above. Check i am able to submit the form with class in html but the same not working in php